# Why can't php function on my machine?

Tags: server, apache2, php

I have an apache2 server, which runs just fine, the problem I have is that whenever I create a php file in my `/var/www/html/` directory, the page loads with nothing to show despite me putting in `phpinfo();`, I already have php installed and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. P.S I'm new to ubuntu and linux.

When I run `sudo apt-get install php` again, it returns:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

meaning I have installed php, thanks!

Comment: Have you try to do simple `echo "Hello World!";` ?

Comment: yea I have done that

Comment: And... is it works fine?

Comment: no it doesn't and that's what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: How is your virtualhost configured?

Comment: I don't understand, I'm running my program locally

Comment: I can configure the other LAMP stuff but I can't seem to figure out the PHP

Comment: Apache server sets its configuration in /etc/apache2/sites-enables/<files>

Comment: Try to run `php` and `php --version`

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the php7.2 module for Apache using `a2enmod php7.2` if you are missing the modules you will need to install them.

After this restart the Apache service: `service apache2 restart`

This *should* fix the issue.

If you are missing any modules I believe the package name for the Apache php7.2 module  is `libapache2-mod-php`

Comment: What does the cmd for that look like?

Comment: The output of `a2enmod php7.2`?

Comment: is it 

sudo apt-get install a2enmod php7.2?

Comment: In terms of commands you need to run, I'd start by installing or checking the status of `libapache2-mod-php`. Run `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php`

Comment: It first said 3 not upgraded, i upgraded and it still does nothing

Comment: but yea i have it installed

Comment: Okay, try running `sudo a2enmod php7.2` and then restart Apache by running `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95439/discussion-between-frogman578-and-synchro).